# How can I recover a Google Analytic account for a Meetup group?

Tags: google-analytics, administration, ownership

I have taken over a Meetup Group, which is a social network that supports Google Analytics tracking code. I have sufficient permission to change the tracking code. However it does not support arbitrary file uploads to a domain or even a directory. I've read through [How to Regain Access to Your Google Analytics Account](http://www.logicsolutions.com/regain-access-google-analytics-account/) but that does not have a solution.

Comment: If you can't add the recovery files, you may just have to change the tracking code and accept that you won't see historical data.

Comment: Do you know who was the person that set it up to start with?   If you could contact them, they could add you.

Comment: I tried that as well. I'm not sure who it is.

Comment: Questions on this site are required to be about [websites under your own control](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You might be able to ask this over at [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), but be sure to review their Help Center's [What topics can I ask about here?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I have reviewed the help centre. Thank you for your help.The new post is https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108040/how-can-i-recover-a-google-analytic-account-for-a-meetup-group